# Get a Count of a Field Including Similar Entries MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hey all I'm trying to parse out any duplicates in an access database. I want the database to be usable for the access illiterate and therefore I am trying to set up queries that can be run without any understanding of the program.

My database is setup where there are occasionally special characters attached to the entries in the Name field. I am interested in checking for duplicate entries based of the fields field1 and name. How can I include the counts for entries with special characters with their non-special character counterparts? Is this possible in a single step or do I need to add a step where I clean the data first?

Currently my code (shown below) only returns counts for entries not including special characters.

```
SELECT 
    table.[field1], 
    table.[Name], 
    Count(table.[Name]) AS [CountOfName]
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    table.[field1], 
    table.[Name]
HAVING 
    (((table.[Name]) Like "*") AND ((Count(table.[Name]))>1));
```

I have tried adding a leading space to the Like statement (Like " *"), but that returns zero results.

**P.S**. I have also tried the Replace statement to replace the special characters, but that did not work.

### field1 ##

- 1234567
- 1234567
- 4567890
- 4567890

### name ##

- brian
- brian
- ted
- ted‡

Results
field1
1234567

name
brian

countofname
2

Comment: Could you show some sample data please? BTW, `*` is a wildcard entry in Access, so * can be * or `Paul` or `whatever you want it to be` or `12358` or `17 Aug 1989` or `http://www.google.co.uk`

Comment: The results for the ted entries are not being counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` works by placing rows into groups where values are the same. So, when you run your query on your data and it groups by `field1` and `name`, you are saying "Put these records into groups where they share a common field1 and name value". If you want `4567890, ted` and `4567890, ted†` to show in the same group, and thus have a count of 2, both the `field1` and `name` have to be the same.

If you only have one or two possible special characters on the end of the names, you could potentially use `Replace()` or `Substring()` to remove all the special chars from the end of the names, but remember you must also `GROUP BY` the new expression you create; you can't `GROUP BY` the original name field or you won't get your desired count. You could also create another column that contains a sanitized name, one without any special character on the end.

I don't have Access installed, but something like this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    table.[field1], 
    Replace(table.[Name], "†", "") AS Name, 
    Count(table.[Name]) AS [CountOfName]
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    table.[field1], 
    Replace(table.[Name], "†", "")
```

Comment: As I stated in my initial post I have tried the replace function before. It seems to work when removing a single character, but not when I try to address all three (†,‡,^). Any suggestions how I can replace the others?

Comment: You will need to nest the `Replace()` statements, something like `Replace(Replace(Replace(table.[Name], "†", ""), "‡", ""), "^", "")`. Be sure to put this in your `SELECT` and your `GROUP BY`. Again, I'm just freehanding the SQL because I don't have an Access install available, but that should work. Depending on the amount of replacements you need to do, you may want to consider keeping a sanitized name in another column and grouping by that.

Comment: Ahhhhhh nesting that's what I was missing and didn't even know it. Wow I just wasted a bunch of time going around in circles. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UdderlyAstray You're welcome, glad you were able to get it resolved.